# VB.net link extraction with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: vb.net, href, html-agility-pack

I was able to extract URLs with simple href tags like this:

```
<a href="http://www.samplesite.com">
```

but my problem is how do i extract a link from an href tag that looks like this?

```
<a href="http://www.wherecreativitygoestoschool.com/vancouver/left_right/rb_test.htm" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','1','AFQjCNHvlwTxfBVEYcqGUnilAZN0uY2IXw','','0CCsQFjAA','','',event)">
Right Brain vs Left Brain Creativity <em>Test</em> at The Art Institute of <b>...</b></a>
```

Here is my complete code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
            Dim WebSource As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.google.com.ph/search?hl=en&as_q=test&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=countryCA&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&tbs=ctr%3AcountryCA&as_filetype=&as_rights=#as_qdr=all&cr=countryCA&fp=1&hl=en&lr=&q=test&start=20&tbs=ctr:countryCA")

        Dim doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
            doc.LoadHtml(WebSource)
            Dim links = GetLinks(doc, "test")
            For Each Link In links
                ListBox1.Items.Add(Link.ToString())
            Next
        End Sub


       Public Class Link
            Public Sub New(Uri As Uri, Text As String)
                Me.Uri = Uri
                Me.Text = Text
            End Sub
            Public Property Text As String
            Public Property Uri As Uri

            Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
                Return String.Format(If(Uri Is Nothing, "", Uri.ToString()))
            End Function
        End Class


        Public Function GetLinks(doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument, linkContains As String) As List(Of Link)
            Dim uri As Uri = Nothing
            Dim linksOnPage = From link In doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                              Where link.Name = "a" _
                              AndAlso link.Attributes("href") IsNot Nothing _
                              Let text = link.InnerText.Trim()
                              Let url = link.Attributes("href").Value
                              Where url.IndexOf(linkContains, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 _
                              AndAlso uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, uri)

            Dim Uris As New List(Of Link)()
            For Each link In linksOnPage
                Uris.Add(New Link(New Uri(link.url, UriKind.Absolute), link.text))
            Next

            Return Uris
        End Function
```

I have noticed that my code does not extract links that ends with `</a>`. Is there anything i can do to modify my code that it would extract links ending with `</a>`?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to grab all of links having 'href' attribute from page:

```
Dim hNodeCol as HTMLNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
```

...if you still need it, ofcourse ;)